# Apache2 ErrorDocument not working on VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, errordocument

My ErrorDocument redirect doesn't appear to be working!

Here is the bottom of my sites-available file:

```
    ...
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

        ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</VirtualHost>
```

If you go to 109.123.109.205/404.php, the error page appears correctly, however, when you go to 109.123.109.205/asdf.php, I just get the bog standard 404 error...

Any insight greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

Your `ErrorDocument` statements look correct. As you are testing this using an IP address you may be picking up the default configuration. Try connecting to the virtualhost using the server's name as defined by the `ServerName` directive.